# Subordination process and Bismut's proof of asymptotic formula for the heat kernel

Tags: pr.probability, differential-topology, brownian-motion, index-theory

J. Bismut proved the asymptotic formula for the heat kernel of the Laplace-Beltrami operator $\Delta$ on a manifold $M$ in one of his well-known books.  Later, in his paper on the index theorem, Bismut said that the result can be extended immediately to the heat equation semi-group for Hodge-Kodaira Laplacian or the Dirac Laplacian, since these (operators) are subordinated to the heat equation semi-group for $\Delta$.  My question is: what is subordination or the subordination process in probability?  If there is such subordination, how can one see that the result can be extended immediately?  The proof of the asymptotic formula by Bismut in his book on Large Deviation is not easy to follow.  Also Bismut mentioned that Malliavin has already used the subordination in his paper on vanishing theorem.

Comment: Bismut's book to which I am referring above is Large Deviations and the Malliavin Calculus.

Comment: Subordination is the composition of a stochastic process by a subordinator (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subordinator_(mathematics) ), i.e. an almost surely increasing Lévy process. You have a process $ (X_t)_t $ and a subordinator $ (s_t)_t $ and you form $ X \circ s = (X_{s_t})_t $. If $X$ is Markovian, then $ X\circ s $ is also Markovian and you can express its semi-group/generator using the generators of $X$ and $s$. A classical example is the Poisson subordination, when you compose a (discrete time) Markov chain by a Poisson process to get a continuous time Markov chain.

Comment: The Bismut result certainly says that the semigroup $e^{t \Delta_H} $ (Hodge-Kodaira) or $ e^{t \Delta_D} $ (Dirac) can be expressed as $ \int e^{s \Delta} K(s,t) ds$ for a certain $ K $ associated with a subordinator. For the Markov chain, if $ \mathbb{E}(f(X_k)|X_0 = x) = M^k f(x) $, then $ \mathbb{E}(f(X_{N_t})|X_0 = x) = e^{t(M - I) }f(x) $ with $M$ a stochastic matrix and $I$ the identity (and $N$ a Poisson process of intensity 1). Condition on $ N_t = k $ to get the formula.

Comment: Synia, thank you for your reply.  I need a bit time to think about it first.

Comment: Synia, you give a good example of subordinated process and subordinator. A subordinator has to be a real valued increasing process of the evolution of time. So $X_s$ is the subordinated process and $s_t$ is the subordinator determining the evolution of time $s$. On the other hand, Bismut was definitely a probabilist in his early career.  He was using the words subordinating process and subordination procedure in his paper on index theorem.  However, the heat equation semi-group for $\Delta$ or the Wiener process takes value in a manifold $M$, so it cannot describe evolution of time.

Comment: (Cont'd from above)  You cannot say it is increasing any more, because it takes value in $M$. So when Bismut talked about subordination in the paper, he probably meant something else.

Comment: Synia, for one of the above comments, I said "Wiener process", it should mean "Brownian motion" in $M$.

Comment: (I understood for the Wiener process). I could not access the Bismut paper, that's why I gave a general definition of subordination. Could you give an accessible link on this paper on the index theorem. I will have a look (I am not a specialist on these questions, but if this is just a question of vocabulary, I can have a try). The subordinator is just an authorised time change, and this is still possible on a manifold (the important thing is that $s \in \mathbb{R}_+$ and not that $X_s \in M$). If you can define the semi-group as $e^{t L}$, this should be possible to make operations on $t$.

Comment: The paper is: The Atiyah-Singer Index theorems I, Journal of Functional Analysis, 57, pp. 56-99 (1984).  You may be able to find it in the site: www.math.u-psud.fr/~bismut, click list of publications.

Comment: Well, this is an extremely hard article !! The subordination, for me, is the theorem 2.5 p. 19, i.e. the equation (2.16), but I would have written it slightly differently (with an integral from 0 to $t$ in the exponential, à la Feynman-Kac). As announced in the paragraph 2.c p. 18, this is such a procedure. To me, it seems that "subordination" means in fact "Feynman-Kac formula" in this article... I didn't have a look at the Malliavin articles cited.

Comment: Synia, I agree with you. Bismut used "subordination" probably in this sense. Bismut's argument maybe is as follows: since the asymptotic formula for the heat kernel of Brownian motion represented by the  Feynman-Kac formula is proved, and since the Hodge Laplacians are subordinated to the heat equation semi-group, i.e., there is a corresponding Feynman-Kac formula for the heat kernel of the Hodge Laplacian using the same diffusion process, not for functions but for sections of some vector bundle, so there is corresponding aysmptotic expansion for the heat kernels for the Hodge Laplacians.

Comment: Yes, I believe this is something like this. I don't know enough these Laplacians, but if they are of the form $ L + M_V $ with the same $L$ and different $V$, this is indeed the case : the FK formula will use the same diffusion. Here, $ L $ is a diffusion operator (second order differential operator without "constant" term, namely term without differentials, for instance $ \sigma^2 (d/dx)^2 + b \, d/dx $ in dimension 1) and $ M_V f = V \cdot f $ (multiplication by the function $V$). This is the typical case where you can apply the FK formula. Is it the case ?

Comment: Synia, yes, that is the case, because there is the Weitzenbock formula in each case, which gives $M_V$ to be a multiplication operator.

Comment: Interesting topic ! :)